# Where is my javascript going wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am fairly new to JS and regular expressions. I was hoping somebody here could help me out with a problem I'm having.

So in my code, what I want to happen is to get an array with each word in the English language in its own index ([here's a link to the .txt file I am reading from](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/wordlist)). So far, I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allWords;
    function getAllWords(list) {
        $.get("wordlist.txt", function (words) {
            var re = "/\w+$/m"
            list = words.split(re);
            console.log(list);
        });
    }
    getAllWords(allWords);
    console.log(allWords);
});
```

But instead of having each word in its own index, it returns an array with all of the words in one index. Can anybody tell me where I went wrong/point me in the right direction? I can clarify more if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `$.get()` in `getAllWords()` is asynchronous which means its internal callback is called sometime later).  You can't just assign its result to a global and expect to use it in the next line.  The Ajax call will not yet have finished.

Comment: There are many other things wrong here too.  Passing an empty `allWords` variable and expecting that an assignment to that argument will somehow return that value is just wrong and it looks like you have regex problems too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call for how to handle results from an ajax call.  It looks like you don't understand asynchronous operations.

Comment: Ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems:

- Regex literal doesn't need to be quoted like `var re = "/\w+$/m";`
- Regex itself is wrong, it should be `var re = /\s+/;` to break a line into words splitting on white spaces.

**Update::** Updated code with possible fixes:

```
re = /\s+/g;
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function getAllWords() {
        $.get("wordlist.txt", function (response) {
            var allWords = response.split(re);
            console.log( allWords );
        });
    }    
});
```

Comment: Yes `\s` also matches `\n` in addition to a space and tab

Comment: There are multiple other problems in this code (wrong handling of async operations, wrong passing of a variable and expecting it to act like a reference, etc...).  The regex is probably the least of the problems.

Comment: Yes that is true. I am not jquery dev but still can see many issues in the code. regex problem was the first one to hit my eyes.

Comment: Well like I said, I am still fairly new to JS in general and this is my first "real" project with it. If you could, will you provide examples of how I can better my code?

Comment: @Vitorossi: You're most welcome, pls do proper testing as I know well about regex but not a jquery expert.

Comment: I'm still surprised this is the accepted answer because this will not work at all due to the async nature of `$.get()`.

Comment: @jfriend00: I added javascript/jquery code as an addendum only with a note in the comments, my main answer as you have noted is on using the correct regex.

Comment: Then, take the jQuery out of your answer and ONLY answer about the regex because your jQuery code simply doesn't work and thus this is a poor reference of an answer (it's an answer with code that won't work).

Comment: I only added after your's and OP's comment but it is updated now.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. The regex is wrong.
2. Passing an undefined argument to `getAllWords()` and somehow expecting the result to end up in that variable.
3. `$.get()` is asynchronous so you can't use it's result in the next line of code.

Here's one approach that would work.  This fixes the regex and adds a callback argument that gets called when the data is available:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getAllWords(fn) {
        $.get("wordlist.txt", function(data) {
            var words = data.split(/\s+/);
            fn(words);
        });
    }
    getAllWords(function(words) {
        console.log(words);
    });
});
```

Or, using jQuery promises (which is my preferred way of handling async operations):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getAllWords(fn) {
        return $.get("wordlist.txt").then(function(data) {
            return data.split(/\s+/);
        });
    }
    getAllWords.then(function(words) {
        console.log(words);
    });
});
```

Comment: So in your first approach, the variable "words" is the same as my array "allWords"? I just want to see if I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: @Vitorossi - sort of.  But I'm using a local variable because global variables are of little use (and bad practice) when using asynchronous operations like `$.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dollar sign from your regex. So do this: `var re = /\w+/m;`